# Jump to previous page after sending data using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

On page A, I use ajax to send data to server. At sever side, after spring controller gets the data, it returns welcome page B. Evergthing works fine on firefox and IE. But on chrome, after ajax call sends data to server successflully, we can get the reponse: the page B I want. But the page B just show for 1 second. Then jump back to page A again. Now idea why? Thanks.

The form html:

```
        <form class="form" id="register-form">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        <input id="password1" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" >
        <input id="password2" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password2">
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <input id="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phonenumber">
        <button onclick="register()" id="register-button">Join us!</button>
    </form>
```

Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({ 
url: "/myporject/user/addUser", 
type: 'GET', 
dataType: 'text', 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
async: false,
cache : false,
data: {
    username:username,
    password:pwd1,
    email:email,
    phonenumber:phone
},
success : function(response) {
    alert("response:" + response);
    document.open();
    document.write(response);
    document.close();
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    alert("error!!!");
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    alert(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
}
});
```

Spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView addUser(
        @RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
        @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
        @RequestParam(value = "phonenumber") String phonenumber) {
    User user = userService.createUser(username, password, email, phonenumber,
            User.ROLE_CUSTOMER);
    ModelAndView myview = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    return myview;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<button type="button" ...>` so that a (standard, non-Ajax) form submit doesn't happen at the same time? Or bind the click handler with jQuery and use `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: I added type="button". Then it solved this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @nnnnnn, really? I didn't know that the `type` can be used to avoid the `event.preventDefault` and click handler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" (e.g. `<button type="button" ...>`) so that a (standard, non-Ajax) form submit doesn't happen at the same time.

Or bind the click handler with jQuery and use event.preventDefault()